# DLMS data decryption

Tags: node.js, smartmeter, dlms

How to decrypt dlms data in nodejs, i want AES GCM GMAC 128 bit with general global ciphering decryption.

I have tried with key but not able to decrypt the data, please give me sample example with nodejs and any other language for how to decrypt data of dlms library.